# I need help transforming a table to a matrix

Tags: r, dplyr

Im looking for an R algorithm to take this table:

```
One Two  Value
  A   B   1002
  A   C   2312
  B   A   6543
  B   C    387
  C   A   9364
  C   B   8429
```

And transform that into this kind of matrix:

```
##       A     B     C
## A     0  6543  9364 
## B  1002     0  8429    
## C  2312   387     0
```

Any considerations? I don't know what the name of the first kind of table is, if there is any. Thanks!

Comment: the package `tidyr` and the function `spread` inside it should be your friend.

Comment: adding to above comment, you probably just need `df %>% spread(Two, Value, fill = 0)`?

Comment: To give you more "searchable" jargon, the operation you're looking for can be called pivot (vs unpivot), or cast (vs melt), or spread (vs gather, that's `tidyr` jargon indeed), or wide format (vs long format)... and I might be forgetting some variations...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/2204410

Comment: `xtabs(Value ~ ., df)`... or transpose it to get your exact expected output `t(xtabs(Value ~ ., df))`

Answer (score 0):

You can go from one representation to the other using `xtabs` and `as.data.frame`.  If `x` is the original data:

```
> xtabs(Value ~ Two + One, x)
   One
Two    A    B    C
  A    0 6543 9364
  B 1002    0 8429
  C 2312  387    0

> as.data.frame(xtabs(Value ~ Two + One, x), responseName = 'Value')
  Two One Value
1   A   A     0
2   B   A  1002
3   C   A  2312
4   A   B  6543
5   B   B     0
6   C   B   387
7   A   C  9364
8   B   C  8429
9   C   C     0
```